# What is the correct way of retrieving an OAuth2 Bearer token in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am making service to service requests using Spring's `WebClient` that require an `OAuth2` bearer token to be added as a header to the request.  I Can do this relatively easily by creating an `ExchangeFilterFunction` that intercepts the request, retrieves an access token, adds it to the header, and continues on.  Since this is not a user request, the `SecurityContextHolder` does not contain an Authentication that would hold an access token for me, so instead of retrieving from that, I would like to get an access token based on my Spring security configuration (currently defined in the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration` and provider properties).

The way I'm doing this now is by `Autowiring` an `OAuth2ClientContext` and then getting the `AccessToken` from it.  Reducing the code only to what I care about for this question, I have:

```
@Component
public class OAuth2WebClientFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        // simple retrieval of the token
        String oAuth2Token = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken().getValue();

        // adding the token to the header of the request
        request = ClientRequest.from(request).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + oAuth2Token).build();
    
        return next.exchange(request);
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I want it to.  However, I have recently upgraded `spring-security-oauth2` to `2.5.0.RELEASE`, and it is saying the `OAuth2ClientContext` is deprecated, but I haven't found a simple replacement for this process.  So is there still a way to get an access token in a relatively simple fashion like above, and if so, how?

Also note: this concept is used elsewhere in the project and not just for the `WebClient`, so I'm looking to see how to properly replace an injected `OAuth2ClientContext`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security provides an exchange filter function called `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`.

> The ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction provides a
> simple mechanism for requesting protected resources by using an
> OAuth2AuthorizedClient and including the associated OAuth2AccessToken
> as a Bearer Token. It directly uses an OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
> and therefore inherits the following capabilities:
>
> An OAuth2AccessToken will be requested if the client has not yet been
> authorized.
>
> authorization_code - triggers the Authorization Request redirect to
> initiate the flow
>
> client_credentials - the access token is obtained directly from the
> Token Endpoint
>
> password - the access token is obtained directly from the Token
> Endpoint
>
> If the OAuth2AccessToken is expired, it will be refreshed (or renewed)
> if an OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider is available to perform the
> authorization

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet for details.

Comment: The thing about that is you need an OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, which I don't have.  I can create a `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` using a `ClientRegistrationRepository` and `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, which already seems much more complicated. Even still, when I use that approach, I manage to get this exception: InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle